# No ping between Nokia (IPSO) and Cisco switch through trunk link

Tags: switch, vlan, firewall, ping, trunk

I have a Nokia and a Cisco switch, connected with one RJ cable. I've configured the switch in trunk mode, and the port on the Nokia with some VLAN number.

I don't have a ping between them, I don't think there should be a trunk configuration on the Nokia, since I couldn't find any info on that issue on the Internet or the official CP documentation.

Am I right in not configuring anything that is "trunk" on the Nokia, or is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that I forgot the command: `switchport mode trunk` on the Cisco switch.

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever looking for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to ping the device if configured on trunk mode but this should be set on certain circumstances only. For end-devices, the best configuration would be on access mode for the vlan in which they are supposed to send traffic through. For example, if you expect the device to obtain its IP address via DHCP and DHCP is configured on the network, broadcasts should go through the vlan you set after the `switchport access vlan <vlan_ID>` command.